# How to execute parallely with 2 browsers (Chrome & Firefox) using one Singleton without error? Is it possible?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, singleton

I declare one Singleton with a driver instance in @BeforeTest annotation and I use it to execute all the tests in @Test annotation with 2 browsers parallely.

My question is when I try to close or quit the driver in @AfterTest, it is thrown an error saying "The FirefoxDriver cannot be used after quit() was called"? Is it possible to resolve it?

Comment: Can you post your code please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A code example is needed, but it sounds like you have a threading problem.

If what you are trying to do is abstract WebDriver configuration from your test classes into one central place, I'm not sure a singleton is the best solution.

If you take a look at how [TestNG threads it's test execution](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parallel-running), you can very easily end up with unexpected WebDriver behavior if the WebDriver instance lives on a class separate from the test.  In your case, this is a singleton.  In my case, when I first encountered this issue, it was a parent class.

The solution I put into place was to use a parent class for all configuration and setup/teardown of the WebDriver, then extend this class with all my test classes.  In order to make this work properly, I had to put my WebDriver on a `ThreadLocal<>`.  By doing this, I was able to ensure each thread (test) had it's own WebDriver instance to use.

`ThreadLocal`s aren't terribly difficult to work with, but more info can be found [here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/threadlocal.html).

There are many other ways to solve this problem, and many of us have found our own way... this is simply my approach.

Comment: Thanks for your approach :)

Comment: You're very welcome.  Please feel free to upvote and/or accept my answer if you've found it helpful.  Many thanks :)